# SVNKit using ssh throws IOException

Tags: java, eclipse, subversive, svnkit

I installed a new subversion repository but I am unable to connect to the repository.

In the old repository it is working as expected. The new repository thorws an exception:

```
org.eclipse.team.svn.core.connector.SVNConnectorException: svn: E210002: There was a problem while connecting to xn--x7h.example.com:22
    at org.polarion.team.svn.connector.svnkit.SVNKitService.handleClientException(SVNKitService.java:59)
    at org.polarion.team.svn.connector.svnkit.SVNKitConnector.listEntries(SVNKitConnector.java:1758)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.extension.factory.ThreadNameModifier.listEntries(ThreadNameModifier.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility.list(SVNUtility.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnstorage.SVNRepositoryContainer.getChildren(SVNRepositoryContainer.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.remote.GetRemoteFolderChildrenOperation.runImpl(GetRemoteFolderChildrenOperation.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.CompositeOperation.runImpl(CompositeOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.LoggedOperation.run(LoggedOperation.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTaskExternal(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.utility.DefaultCancellableOperationWrapper.run(DefaultCancellableOperationWrapper.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.utility.ScheduledOperationWrapper.run(ScheduledOperationWrapper.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E210002: There was a problem while connecting to xn--x7h.example.com:22
    at org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException.fromException(ClientException.java:117)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.getClientException(SVNClientImpl.java:1539)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.list(SVNClientImpl.java:189)
    at org.polarion.team.svn.connector.svnkit.SVNKitConnector.listEntries(SVNKitConnector.java:1745)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210002: There was a problem while connecting to xn--x7h.example.com:22
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNSSHConnector.open(SVNSSHConnector.java:145)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.open(SVNConnection.java:77)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.openConnection(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1273)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.getLatestRevision(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:172)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:119)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:195)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:46)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteList.run(SvnRemoteList.java:36)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteList.run(SvnRemoteList.java:1)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.list(SVNClientImpl.java:187)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to xn--x7h.example.com:22
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:817)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshHost.openConnection(SshHost.java:225)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshHost.openSession(SshHost.java:153)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshSessionPool.openSession(SshSessionPool.java:85)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNSSHConnector.open(SVNSSHConnector.java:122)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:92)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:231)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:769)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not match.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.handleMessage(KexManager.java:413)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:765)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:480)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your domain contains unicode characters? `xn--x7h` is `⚙`, no guarantee that this is the issue, but I would be very careful doing such things.

Comment: @luk2302 No the domain contains no unicode character. Even if, the conciderations from the IAB (I guess you meant that) belonging to unicode characters who are confusably similar to alphanumeric characters. ⚙ is no such an confusably similar to alphanumeric character. Since the stacktrace shows a KexManager-line (Key-Exchange=kex I guess) telling me the connection has been acomplished a stage that do not belong to DN anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked on server-side what is going on. So I called `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` and discovered a message that the client and the server was not able to agree on matching kex-algorithms.

Finally my solution was to enable the line

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

to the corresponding

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

File and restart the sshd-server.